# What is IV-V4/2-iii-vi-ii-V-I called?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

In many pop songs I've seen this progression:

> IV - V4/2 - iii - vi - ii - V - I

What is this called?

To me it looks like a modified circle of fifths progression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, it's a modified circle-of-fifths progression, with V4/2 standing in for vii<sup>o</sup>. It does not have a particular name.

Comment: yes, iii-vi-ii-V  is a diatonic fifth fall progression. But what about V4/2? I've never encountered this notation. Can you explain what it stands for and tell me a source?

Comment: V4-2 is a V chord in third inversion; that is, with the chordal seventh in the bass and a fourth and a second above. It comes from [figured bass notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figured_bass#Numbers)..

Comment: I see: the dominant 7 ( 3rd inversion) never seen the back slash! V2 would be sufficient. I didn’t expect the RN terminology in Pop songs.

Comment: V4/2 has ^4 in the bass, not ^7.  When the bass of the dominant seventh chord is ^7, it's in first inversion, so V6/5.

Comment: @phoog Thanks. Dumb mistake I added to the post last night. Rolled back.

Comment: You're welcome.  Instead of rolling back, you might consider correcting the reasoning.  The impulse to explain _why_ V4/2 can stand in for viiº is a good one.  (I'm sure you know this, but for other readers who might not, the usual explanation for the similarity is that V7 is related to viiº by having the same three pitches plus one more.  Specifically, both chords contain ^7, ^2, and ^4, while V7 additionally contains ^5.  While the bass of V4/2 isn't the same as that of viiº in root position, it _is_ the same as that of viiº6/4.)

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli the slash (not backslash, typically) seems to be the best way to render multiple figures on this site.  As you most likely know, they're usually written in vertical alignment, and when they appear in Roman numeral analysis they are written to the right of the Roman numeral.  Adding the slash is a bit weird, but alternatives are worse.  For example, V42 looks like it has something to do with "forty-two," which is just confusing.  Superscript and subscript tags don't work in comments, don't give vertically aligned results, and don't support triple figures.